# How to design and set up user and role tables to retrieve values from both?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

In Flask there is a function that loads the user from a session cookie or sets it before requests, but what is the proper way to determine what role/permissions this user have using SQL?

The tables:

```
CREATE TABLE app_user (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR (500) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE role (
  role_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  role_description VARCHAR (25)
);

INSERT INTO role (role_description) VALUES
  ('New'),
  ('Active'),
  ('Moderator');

CREATE TABLE user_role (
  app_user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  app_user_role_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (app_user_id) REFERENCES app_user (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (app_user_role_id) REFERENCES role (role_id)
);
```

Flask, loading user:

```
@bp.before_app_request
def load_logged_in_user():
    user_id = session.get('user_id')

    if user_id is None:
        g.user = None
    else:
        db = get_db().cursor()
        load_user = db.execute(
            'SELECT * FROM app_user WHERE id = %s', (user_id,)
            # SELECT u.id, username, app_user_role_id
            # WHERE u.id = %s', (user_id,)
            # FROM app_user u JOIN user_role r ON u.id = app_user_id
            # Don't know how to do this, or how it is usually done
            # As it stands now it doesn't make any sense, as I have 
            # been fiddling with it for too long.

        )
        load_user = db.fetchone()
        g.user = load_user
```

And is it better in terms of performance to put everything in the user table instead? Because there may be much info that is not always needed, so would several tables make it faster or just create a need for many more connections?

Is it normal to use ORM's in huge applications or to write raw SQL? Is it true that writing raw SQL increases the performance up to three times in comparison to using an ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the user and it's privilieges you could use a join :

```sql
select app_user.username, role.role_description
  from app_user
  join user_role
    on app_user.id = user_role.app_user_id
  join role
    on user_role.app_user_role_id = role.id
  where app_user.id = %s
```

As for your second question I would certainly use a few tables as you did instead of just one, as relationnal databases just work that way.

If you'd like to use a unique table, you should probably look for document oriented databases, like mongoDB or ElasticSearch (ES might be overkill for a small project).

https://www.mongodb.com

https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch

**Edit :** for your new question

The advantage of using an ORM is that it makes the coding part much faster, easier and safer.

Of course sometimes there will be complicated requests that an ORM won't optimize properply.
I'm thinking about django's ORM, it's known that in a few cases of complicated requests it doesn't shine.
But then, for those specific cases, you can always write your own queries manually to get better performances.

There is an interesting article on the topic : https://medium.com/@hansonkd/performance-problems-in-the-django-orm-1f62b3d04785